# Overcoming JavaScript Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to using JavaScript to perform requests, however I want to get the HTML of a page from https://www.halowaypoint.com but keep getting an error response of "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/players/PLAYER/halo4. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'URL' is therefore not allowed access." (PLAYER has been substituted).

I've heard CORS being mentioned several times after looking around, but I don't have server side access and I'm not sure how to reflect this in the request. Is there a way around this?

This is the code I've used so far:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/players/PLAYER/halo4',
    dataType:'text',
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
    },
    headers: {
    },
    success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
    },
    error: function() {
            alert('Error')
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header can only be added server-side, or the internet would be *very* insecure.  You could write your own server code (on your own server) to download the page for you and call that instead.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! I feared it may have been client side. I'll ask the server host for permission.